# How to show the following limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

Let $f:\mathbb{N^*} \to \mathbb{N^*}$ an injective function. Show that $\displaystyle \sum _{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{f(n)}{n^2}=+\infty$. I tried to :

- Show that $f(n) \ge n$ for all $n$, but i think i've found that's false. ($f(1)=2$ $f(2)=1$ for example)
- Let $(S_n)_n$ a sequence such that $S_n= \frac{f(n)}{n^2}$, then using some criterion like Alembert criterion's, yet it didn't work.

Any help, please !

Comment: Your sum doesn't make sense already for $n=0$.

Comment: It's still starting at $\displaystyle\frac{f(0)}{0^2}$.

Comment: Do you know Abel's sum formula?

Answer (score 2):

For all $n \geq 1$, let $$S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{f(k)}{k^2}$$

You have that
$$S_{2n}-S_n = \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \frac{f(k)}{k^2} \geq \frac{1}{(2n)^2} \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} f(k) \geq \frac{1}{4n^2}(1+2+...+n)=\frac{n(n+1)}{8n^2}\geq \frac{1}{8}$$

(justification of $\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} f(k) \geq 1+2+...+n$ : the sum is made by $n$ distinct integers - because $f$ is injective -, so it is greater or equal to the smallest sum of $n$ distinct integers you can have, which is $1+2+...+n$.)

So $S_{2n}-S_n$ does not tend to $0$, so $(S_n)$ does not converge.

Comment: There is a crazy downvoter here ! Why are the two answers downvoted ? Any explanation ?...

Comment: I don't know. My upvote tried to compensate the unfair downvote. But you *could* explain in a word or two why $\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} f(k) \geq 1+2+...+n$. If mere strings of inequalities were obvious to everybody, many questions here wouldn't be asked.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Thanks for the comment, I precised a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

Introduce $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{f(k)}{k^2}$. Notice that the first $n$ values of $f(n)$ must be different because of injection. The minimum value of $S_n$ is obtained when the first $n$ values of $f(n)$ are $1,2,3\dots n$.

First show that for any $k,l$ such that $k<l\le n$:

$$\frac{k}{k^2}+\frac{l}{l^2}<\frac{l}{k^2}+\frac{k}{l^2}$$

This is obvious, because you can easily show that it is equivalent to:

$$kl^2+lk^2<l^3+k^3$$

$$0<l^2(l-k)-k^2(l-k)$$

$$0<(l^2-k^2)(l-k)$$

...which is true for $l>k$. It means that the minimum value of $S_n$ is achieved when $f(k)=k$ for $k=1,2,\dots,n$

It means that:

$$S_n\ge S_{n_{min}}=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{k^2}=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}=H_n$$

...where $H_n$ is the $n$-th harmonic number.

It means that:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}S_n\ge\lim_{n\to \infty}H_n=\infty$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{f(n)}{n^2}=\infty$$